# jquery---validate the form

Tags: jquery

the html code:

```
<labelName</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />
  <label class="error" for="name" id="name_error">This field is required.</label>
```

the js code:

```
               var name = $("input#name").val();
    if (name == "") {
    $("label#name_error").show();
    $("input#name").focus();
    return false;
  }
```

why use the return false;? could i use exit? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your validation code is called on a onSubmit event chain such as in

```
$('form').onSubmit(function(event) {
  // do validation
  return false;
}
```

return false is used to block the form submission to continue. Without it the form submission will continue and the action page will be loaded.

other then "return false;", you could also add "event.preventDefault();" for blocking the form submission.

The same method could also be used in other event. For example, if you want to block a click event from a link (which by default would load the page specified on href), you could do :

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: but this way you need to send post, after you validate fields, right?

Comment: not necessarily.. if you want for the form to be submitted in the background using ajax without reloading the page.. then yes.. you need to serialized the form then sent it using post.. but, if you simply want to do a client side js validation.. you could validate, then return false IF validation failed.. of course, you don't need to return false, or preventDefault, if validation passed..

Answer (score 0):

When you `return false`, you're actually preventing the default behavior (submission in this case).

Comment: could i use return 0 or exit ?

Comment: @runeveryday - Just use return false.  It's what most people would expect to see to suppress the behavior.  You might be able to use return 0, but why make everyone else think harder about what you're doing when they may be one day looking at your code trying to fix a system critical bug.  If you're curious, there's nothing wrong with that.  Try it :)  But please use false.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no `exit` in javascript!